# ScrollView does not respond to keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I have a problem with EditText scroll behaviour in ScrollViews, normally it scrolls up content inside scroll if keyboard opens over it. But if you fill the layout inside the scrollview dynamically, keyboard push up whole screen, anyone else had this problem before. 
Thanks in advance.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_area" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentHolder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This sample works normal, linear layout scrolls in scroll view but it shows scrolls even keyboard closed. I can not use fixed heights.

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_area" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentHolder"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I have tried xml below, it works as expected on a new project but push up window in my project. I have found some other people having this problem, I'll share solution asap i found it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentHolder"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you doing add new View inside LinearLayout which Parent View is ScrollView?

Comment: Yes, using linearLayout inside scrolView. Pushing views into @+id/contentHolder

Comment: You have more then one EditText in side LinearLayout right.Can you please show screen shot of your problem.

Comment: Couldnt share screen shot, but added new layout. Found the problem btw, it all about fullscreen theme. Thanks for response.

Comment: Yes ,Android Still now support softKeyboard resize when Activity is full Screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/is_logo_iphone"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Problem is "Fullscreen" theme does not support resize. Using

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```

solves the problem. 
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your scrollview is resizeable. Try to set the height of your scrollview to match_parent instead.

Try also setting android:fillViewport="true" inside your scrollview.

Also you wouldn't happen to have added something like following within your activity tag of your manifest: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` That would pretty much ruin all our effort. If you have following within the manifest remove it.

Your probably have to configure your manifest. [Here is a list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) of possible configurations for soft keyboard. It might be `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` you want to use.

Comment: i have tried like every combination, but this doesn't work too. Thanks.

Comment: @ymutlu added another possible solution

Comment: Thanks, tried that but no responce. I might be doing something wrong. Tried this with an empty projects that works well.

Comment: Hmm I added another possible culprint :)